# Converting from unsigned Char* to unsigned int

Tags: c++, types, compiler-errors

When I do the following, I get this error:

**../src/Sample.cpp:19: error: cast from \u2018UINT8*\u2019 to \u2018UINT8\u2019 loses precision**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char UINT8;
typedef unsigned int UINT32;

#define UNUSED(X) X=X

int main() {
    UINT8 * a = new UINT8[34];
    UINT32 b = reinterpret_cast<UINT8>(a);

    UNUSED(b);

    return 0;
}
```

How would I go about solving this. Keep in mind I am not trying to convert string to unsigned long, rather converting char* (the ADDRESS value ) to int.

Thanks

Solution:

Turns out that this problem has to do with the pointer size. On a 32 bit machine, the pointer size is 32 bit, and for 64 bit machine is of course 64. The above wont work on a 64 bit machine, but will on a 32 bit machine. This will work on a 64 bit machine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

typedef  uint8_t UINT8;
typedef int64_t UINT32;

#define UNUSED(X) X=X

int main() {
    UINT8 * a = new UINT8[34];
    UINT32 b = reinterpret_cast<UINT32>(a);
    UNUSED(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling for a 32-bit architecture?

Comment: Remember, you are trying to store 34 bytes of data into 4 bytes. The error says it all.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw, no its a 64 bit
Yeah just realized that thanks the code is causing issue because it was originally using 32 bit compiler.

Comment: @Anonymous: If your compiler supports it, you should use the standard integer types from `<cstdint>` or `<stdint.h>`. In particular, `std::uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be large enough to store a pointer value. And even on a 32-bit platform, casting to `<UINT8>` won't work.

Comment: @Mike Seymour I agree, I switched to 32 bit compilation. That how I was to suppose to compile the whole time.

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*) you can use this code to convert:

```
int b = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a);
```

or variations thereof.  I think static_cast will work too.

Of course a has to be l-value (able to be assigned to) to get the address of it.  For non-l-values, you need to use a function and the good old union trick will work:

```
int Pointer2Int (void* p)
{
    union { void* p; int i; } converter;
    converter.p = p;
    return converter.i;
}
```

Comment: Excellent Idea for conversion, but issue is using a 32 bit program, and trying to compile with a 64 bit compilation. The above code doesn't work cause the int is 32, and the pointer is 64. But +1 the union idea.

Comment: Thanks, and that's why I said assuming sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*).  So your code needs to use long long, _int64 or just long depending on your compiler.  C/C++ type system is not the best really.

Comment: I switched my compilation to 32 bits, and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure using reinterpret_cast here is undefined behavior. Reading `unsigned char*` as `unsigned int` breaks strict aliasing.

Comment: @Timo No it works  as long as you are certain that the pointer size is the same as the unsigned int

Comment: @Anonymous: `reinterpret_cast<UINT32>(a)` is ok, but `*reinterpret_cast<UINT32*>(&a)` is UB according to $3.10/10.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a good idea, but the line should read:

```
UINT32 b = reinterpret_cast<UINT32>(a);
```

`reinterpret_cast` takes the type of the destination type as the template parameter.

With the correct type g++ will *tell you* that it isn't a good idea:

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘char’ to type ‘int’
```

see Cthutu's answer for a more correct approach.

Comment: Actually as I mentioned in the question, that is not the issue. The issue that the compiler complains in loss of precision. I just figured out I am trying to compile for a 64 bit system. This means the pointer size is 64 bits as oppose to the 32 bit. This will not work unless I use a 64 bit integer.

Comment: That's why I said assuming sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*).  But of course if sizeof(int) < sizeof(void*) you don't want to be making this cast :)

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to :

int *a;
char b[64];
int c;

a = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));

sprintf(b, "%d", a);

c = atoi(b);

Comment: @ Skippy Thanks, but as I mention in the question, "Keep in mind I am not trying to convert string to unsigned long, rather converting char* (the ADDRESS value ) to int."

Comment: then I meant %x instead of %d. Sorry.